# Issue with the Angular CLI

Tags: angular

I installed the Angular CLI using the command prompt but I get an error with the 
@angular-devkit/build-angular.

All else is fine.

Any ideas as to why?

[image]

And when I run: ng serve -o

I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some more context? What is the error? What commands are you doing that can reproduce the error?

Comment: Is `@angular-devkit/build-angular` in your package.json devDependencies?

Comment: Yes. Note: I removes some to fit in this comment:   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }

Comment: try to pull previous version of @angular/cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in the package json but angular CLI cannot find then it means that you did not install the devkit

```
npm install
```